# How to get some data from a spread sheet to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to bring the first 7 column from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet using google app script but I honestly searched a lot and didn't find a way to do so.

```
function MoveCode(){
      var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zU__ccPIMst54whmyrbmRnDRRjOtQBFPzXhw6NsFqpU/edit#gid=432949714");//369
      var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sourcing");
      var wpLink1 = sheet1.getRange("A2:G").getValues();
      var ssData1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("This-Spread-sheet");
      var sheetPrime1 = ssData1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var data = sheet1.getRange("A2:G").getValues();
      sheetPrime1.
}
```

I want to move the code in a way where if i update the first one it would be updated in the second one.

If you need more explanation please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Coopers example. I think what you want is everytime you change a value in sheet1 it will automatically update in sheet2.  You could either use an onEdit limited to the first 7 columns of sheet1 to copy the value to sheet2.  Or here is script that creates a forumla in each cell of sheet2 to the cell in sheet1.  But you really only need to run this once unless you change the size of either spreadsheet.

```
function moveCode() {
  try {
    const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    //const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");//or url whatever
    const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  // source
    const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet2');  // destination
    var srange = ssh.getDataRange();
    var formulas = [];
    var i=0;
    var j= 0;
    var row = null;
    // srange.getNumRows()-1 because skip the first row
    for( i=0; i<srange.getNumRows()-1; i++ ) {
      row = [];
      for( j=1; j<8; j++ ) {
        row.push("=Sheet1!"+String.fromCharCode(64+j)+(i+2).toString());  // A = 65
      }
      formulas.push(row);
    }
    dsh.getRange(2,1,formulas.length,formulas[0].length).setValues(formulas);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What i understand is that coopers code doesn't update the cell when its changed  in the other sheet right?

Comment: Also, may I ask what is (=Sheet3!) ?

Comment: Sorry I used Sheet3 and Sheet4 in my test case and changed to Sheet1 and Sheet2 to match Cooper's example.  It should be "Sheet1!".

Comment: I think the formula will only work if both sheets are in the same Spreadsheet which is not my case. Im dealing with 2 spreadsheets.  Do you think I can add any changes?

Answer (score 2):

#### Move first seven columns

```
function MoveCode(){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");//or url whatever
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1,7).getValues();
  dsh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: I did that and i got this error "The number of rows in the range must be at least 1."

Comment: what line was the error on

Comment: const vs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1,7).getValues();

Comment: how many rows do you have in your source sheet

Comment: The one i wanna move the data to --> 1000 empty lines     The one i wanna get the data from 1000 lines and the data i wanna get is 242 lines

Comment: Are the sheet names correct?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that

Comment: I can't explain it it works for me.

Comment: Alright, Thank you so much. I will try to figure it out